# Get elements of typescript "tree" object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object that looks like the following :

[image]

It contains objects that also can contains object : it is like a tree.

How can I can a list of the different branches (as list) of this object.

To be more clear, for the previous example, I want a list like this :

```
[['Activity_06jvf7d','Activity_10kmald', 'Activity_1ynobrq'], ['Activity_02uytcw', 'Activity_0zjdtqq', etc.], etc.]
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the result you want has the keys in an order defined by how they show up on the image. But keys of a Javascript object are not ordered. This makes the result non-deterministic. For example,

```
let tree = {
  alpha: {
    beta: {
      gamma: null
    },
    delta: {
      epsilon: null
    }
  }
}
```

can result in

```
[['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'], ['delta', 'epsilon']]
```

as well as

```
[['alpha', 'delta', 'epsilon'], ['beta', 'gamma']]
```

Are both okay?

---

Since any possible result is okay, here's a solution:

```
function buildKeyLists(node: any)
{
  let result  = [];
  let current = [];

  function helper(node: any) {
    if (node === null) {
      result.push(current);
      current = [];
      return;
    }

    for (let key in node) {
      current.push(key);
      helper(node[key]);
    }
  }

  helper(node);

  return result;
}
```

And an example:

```
buildKeyLists({
  Activity_06jvf7d: {
    Activity_10kmald: {
      Activity_1ynobrq: null
    },
    Activity_02uytcw: {
      Activity_0zjdtqq: {
        Activity_003ipe4: {
          Activity_1wl99tz: {
            Activity_0vgcvta: {
              Activity_0wz8mrj: null,
            },
            Activity_02oisqw: {
              Activity_0ibjg00: null
            }
          }
        },
        Activity_13l7ctn: {
          Activity_1cpcqnx: null
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

might return

```
[["Activity_06jvf7d", "Activity_10kmald", "Activity_1ynobrq"], ["Activity_02uytcw", "Activity_0zjdtqq", "Activity_003ipe4", "Activity_1wl99tz", "Activity_0vgcvta", "Activity_0wz8mrj"], ["Activity_02oisqw", "Activity_0ibjg00"], ["Activity_13l7ctn", "Activity_1cpcqnx"]]
```